# Make liquibase output be spooled to the current spool file when running using sqlcl

Tags: oracle, liquibase, sqlcl

Assume we have the following set of scripts:

test.sql

```
create or replace view asdas
as
select 1 val from dual
/
```

controller.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<databaseChangeLog
  xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
                      http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.9.xsd">
    <changeSet author="tim" id="01_tab1_seq" runAlways="true" >
      <sqlFile dbms="oracle"
               endDelimiter=";"
               path="test.sql"
               splitStatements="true"
               stripComments="false"/>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

main.sql

```
spool output.log
lb update -changelog controller.xml
spool off
exit
```

When calling `main.sql` file I get the following output:

```
roman@UBUNTU-LT:/mnt/c/Users/%USERNAME%/Desktop/preset$ sql testuser/testuser@dev-db1 @main.sql

SQLcl: Release 21.1 Production on Thu Jul 22 16:36:34 2021

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Thu Jul 22 2021 16:36:37 +03:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Standard Edition 2 Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.7.0.0.0

SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> set scan on
SQL> set linesize 4000
SQL> spool output.log
SQL> lb update -changelog controller.xml
ScriptRunner Executing: create or replace view asdas
as
select 1 val from dual
/Liquibase Executed:create or replace view asdas
as
select 1 val from dual
/

######## ERROR SUMMARY ##################
Errors encountered:0

SQL> spool off
SQL> exit
Disconnected from Oracle Database 19c Standard Edition 2 Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.7.0.0.0
```

And what I see in `output.log`:

```
SQL> lb update -changelog controller.xml

######## ERROR SUMMARY ##################
Errors encountered:0

SQL> spool off
```

Instead I want to see the whole log output that I see on the screen. Can I somehow force `sqlcl` to write it to the file I spool to?

I tried to add `-log` option to `lb update` but `sqlcl` just creates file with something looking like timestamp at the end of the name but this file is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a bug. Whatever you see in the console should be going into the SPOOL file. I'll log the bug for you - thanks for the test case & report!